# Javascript React Search Function displaying result from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, search, filter

Currently I am working on a React app with a search function trying to fetch JSON data and displaying a matched search result on the website

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
export default function PractitionerSearch() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/practitioners", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => { console.log(response); });
            if (!res) {
                return Error(`Error! status: ${res}`);
            } else if (res.status === 200) {
                return res
            }
            const data = await res.json();
            setData(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const filtered = data.filter((practitioner) =>
        data.includes(practitioner.address[1])
    );

    return (
        <div className="App" style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
            <label className='form-label' htmlFor='name'>
                Practitioner Name:
            </label>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    id='name'
                    value={name.name}
                    onChange={(event) => setName({
                        ...name,
                        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
                    })}
                />
                <button className="search__button" type='Submit'>
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
            <ul>
                {filtered.map((practitioner) => {
                    return <li>{practitioner.name}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );

}
```

and here's an example of the JSON

```
"practitioners": [
    {
      "address": [
        {
          "addr1": "12 W 12 Dr",
          "addr2": "",
          "city": "Moon",
          "fax": "",
          "insurances": [],
          "isPrimary": "false",
          "phone": "5555555555",
          "state": "PA",
          "zip": "55555"
        },
        {
          "addr1": "13 W 13 Dr",
          "addr2": "",
          "city": "North Pole",
          "fax": "",
          "insurances": [],
          "isPrimary": "false",
          "phone": "8888888888",
          "state": "ND",
          "zip": "88888"
        },
        {
          "addr1": "14 W 14 Dr",
          "addr2": "",
          "city": "Somewhereville",
          "fax": "",
          "insurances": [],
          "isPrimary": "true",
          "phone": "2222222222",
          "state": "AZ",
          "zip": "88888"
        }
      ],
      "credential": [
        "PT",
        "DPT"
      ],
      "first_name": "DAVE",
      "gender": "m",
      "last_name": "JONES",
      "npi": "2342143124",
      "specialty": [
        "Physical Therapist"
      ]
    },
```

When I console log the response, I get...

(25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{address: Array(3), credential: Array(2), first_name: 'JOY', gender: 'f', last_name: 'SCOTT', …}

But not getting anything displayed on the page

---

Got it sorted out! Below is the updated code:

```
export default function PractitionerSearch() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/practitioners", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => setData(response))
                .then(response => { console.log(response); });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    console.log("dataState", data);
    
    const filtered = data.filter((practitioner) =>
        practitioner.first_name.includes(name)
    );
    console.log("filtered", filtered)

    return (
        <div className="App">
                <label className='form-label' htmlFor='name'>
                    Practitioner Name:
                </label>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        className="form-input"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        id='name'
                        value={name}
                    onChange={(event) => setName(
                            event.target.value
                        )}
                    />
                    <button className="search-button" type='Submit'>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            <div>
                <ul className="map">
                    {filtered.map((practitioner, index) => {
                        console.log(practitioner);
                        return <li key={index}>{practitioner.first_name}</li>;
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You're only telling us what went correctly.

Comment: I am asking how to display a matched search result on the website

Comment: while printing respons can you try this .then(response => { console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); });

Comment: Suresh, Am I correct that will only console log the response and won't show the result of a searched word?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
.then(response => { console.log(response); });
```

should be:

```
.then(response => setData(response))
```

Comment: Made the update but no changes...